# How do I get Pet Carriers?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've been playing Fallout Shelter a lot lately. I'd like to know how you get pet carriers. Is it only from in app purchases or can the be unlocked? I recently unlocked the fitness room if that gives any indication.

Answer (score 2):

You should get the first pet carrier for free, at least that was the case if you'd sign in after the update that provided the game with pets and pet carriers. I don't know if you still get your first pet carrier for free if you'd do that post-update.

Other than that, the pet carriers need to be bought. When the update launched, several game news websites reported the same explanation:

"Pets, like Mister Handy, can be purchased separately via “pet carriers,” and overseers will receive one free carrier after updating." ([source](http://www.gamezebo.com/2015/12/10/fallout-shelter-update-adds-pets-eviction-and-holiday-cheer/))

[Some people](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/178144-fallout-shelter/72971333) report that only a small part of the pets, like Mr. Handy, can be unlocked by completing challenges.

Comment: Didn't buy anything. Only completing challenges. Have cat with exp boost and dog with return speed boost.

Comment: Some challenges reward pet carriers. Pets can also be found in lunch boxes.

Answer (score 1):

From what I think, they are probably a rare drop from LunchBoxes, like Mr.Handy.
I haven't played the game in a good while so don't 100% trust this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You actually can get pets from lunchboxes, I've gotten a pet from a lunchbox.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can get both [Mr.Handy's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdXeZ.jpg) and pets as objective rewards now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get pets from the shop, lunchboxes,completing challenges( though rare) and I've heard rumour that they can be found in the wasteland, but that is yet to be confirmed.